# How to get callback after signing in google auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

I have an endpoint that's access user to sign-in Goole auth,

I handle it inside webView,

it's work and the user sign in with his email/password and after that his data saved on the server-side DB, but I want after user sign in getting the callback a response, I don't know how can i handle it?

here's my code

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <WebView
        userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19"
        source={{uri: 'https://www.mySiteHere.com/api/google'}}
      />
</View>
```

[image: sc]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get data with the property of onMessage of webview
"see the documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#onmessage"

```
handleMessage = (event) => {
        console.log("On Message", event.nativeEvent.data);
}
 <WebView
   ref={(component) => (this.webView = component)}
   onMessage={this.handleMessage}
 />
```

Comment: can add more detail/example about handleMessage function?

Comment: you can first console what the data you are getting then make your own code
I hope now you will get the point (see the updated code)

Comment: it's not log anything, this should be sent by back end dev right?

Comment: no it always log when the webview will response you with data

Comment: sadly i can't see anything

Comment: if you want o authenticate with google you may use the "react-native-app-auth", this will help you

Comment: try to bind in <Webview> onMessagae{()=>this.handleMessage()} now see if it gives log or not